# Is there a way to reduce a motherboard chipset load in Linux?

Tags: linux, temperature, cooling, chipset

I'm interested in reducing the load on the motherboard chipset, or at least, finding what causes the overheating...

I have an HP ProBook 4720s with Ubuntu 12.04, which is slightly overheating. The laptop has an motherboard with the **Intel HM57 Express** chipset (TDP 3.5W), which becomes quite hot (59-64 degrees Celsius), even if the laptop stays idle. The problem is also described here: [notebookreview](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-business-class-notebooks/560859-hp-probook-4720s-hot-spot-under-touchpad.html). From that forum, I think, that the problem is not related to the OS.

The Intel HM57 chip is not connected to the cooling system and has only it's own very small heatsink (radiator) without fan. Also, there is no air flow there (the chipset is located under touchpad, and the laptop case has absolutely no airways there). Changing the thermal grease brings nothing.

However, my idea is not to fix the hardware issues (e.g., cooling system, which is hardly possible for me), but find out, why the chipset is so hot. What makes a load on it? And I hope that it's possible to reduce this load and, therefore, cool down it a bit (hopefully, at least 5 degrees down).

**So, the question is:** How to investigate the load on chipset under Linux? Is there a way to reduce it?

Thank you in advance,

Kind Regards,

Andrey Sapegin.

P.S. I have already asked the same question on the Ubuntu forums (no answers yet): [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2160831)...

P.P.S. What I have found out so early, is that ASPM ([Active State Power Management used to manage PCI-e devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management)) is not enabled. The dmesg says:

```
ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM
```

Unfortunately, 'pcie_aspm=force' and 'i915.i915_enable_rc6=1' kernel options do not help to fix this issue. However, I'm not sure that ASPM and high chipset load are connected...

EDIT: I tried powertop and fixed all tunables to 'Good' (autosuspend for USB, SATA power management, disable NMI watchdog, etc.). But the chipset temperature hasn't changed...

Comment: My laptop's AMD PCH is also a little warmer in Linux than Windows. Not very hot through but warm (in Windows it is room temperature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely you will be able to solve your problems with software. The southbridge is outside of OS control. The OS has no bearing on how much load the chipset is under. The PCH on the HM57 platform control things such as USB, network and HDD connectivity. Typically the *TJ. Max* for a PCH is about **90C**, so unless you're hitting that limit or have problem with freezing or crashes I wouldn't bother to fix it. Granted this might be a design flaw but there is nothing you can do software vise to ease the load on the PCH.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Actually, I don't worry about the temperature of the chipset itself, I just don't like that the laptop is sometimes too hot for me under the touchpad. And I thought that if I enable something LIKE PCI-e power management, which would disable some unused devices (say, Bluetooth, or USB controller, or webcam, if it's not already disabled), the chipset could cool down a bit...

Comment: AND YES, my laptop freezes sometimes, but I can't find a reason. That's why I started looking on the temperature. But I don't know the cause and can't say that it's because of the chipset.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd run `ps`on linux and try to remove those processes that seem expensive or heavy. Overheating used to happen for me for a HP laptop when I compiled programs and compilation is a low priority task, so if you have a task that is overheating the hardware you might try and change the priority of the task. There are more gears to pull with process management, you can read about your operating system by Anders Tanenbaum to learn how to schedule your os and you can ask more spec about linux on the linux and unix site we got here on stackexchange.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't like the answer. I'm talking about chipset load, and not about the CPU/RAM load. The 'ps' command, however, will not help in any case. Also I do not see any connection to process management and process scheduling.